# Django group by jalali week number

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, jalali-calendar

I'm working on django api using a PostgreSQL database. The model has a date field representing a travel time (in jalali format) and an integer field representing number of passengers for that travel.

I'm using [django_jalali](https://github.com/slashmili/django-jalali) to handle jalali date queries.

```
from django_jalali.db import models as jmodels

class TravelReport( models.Model ):

   travel_date = jmodels.jDateField(verbose_name="تاریخ سفر")
   passengers = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to aggregate sum of passengers for each week number in a jalali year. This is the query I'm using:

```
queryset= TravelReport.objects.annotate(week=F("travel_date__week")).values("week").annotate(total_passengers=Sum("passengers"))
```

Here is my problem: Django lookup **__week** is returning Georgian week number not jalali week number. For example week number for a travel date with jdatetime.date(1390, 5, 12) should be 19 but my query is returning 31.

What are my options to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Lets work out options:

1. override the lookup method to work using the jalali calender format.
2. convert your dates to gregorian format and store in another field, and call a function taht takes as input jalali format date, and sends the reciprocating gregorian format date to the lookup field.
3. Keep the number of passengers for a week stored in a separate field, with key as jalali calender weekname and value will be the number of passengers for that week.

Comment: About point 1 and 2: Django-jalali under the hood stores dates in gregorian format in database. Also the maintainers of the package have implemented only two lookups: __year and __date. Other lookups like __day __week and __month returns django's default implementation. But I'm interested if there is a way to override __week lookup?